# Can sgame work together with array?

Tags: arrays

When I insert a game environment provided by "sgame", all the other environments which are related to "array" will break.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,sgame}
\usepackage{array,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{game}{3}{2}
  & F     & O    \\
F & 2, 2  & 0, 1 \\
O & 0, 0  & 1, 3 \\
P & 0, 0  & 1, 3
\end{game}


\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth - 3cm}|p{1cm}<{foo}}
   Caption1 & Caption2\\
   Text & \\
   Text & \\
   Text & \\
   % much more rows
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

So can I make game work together with array in my document? Thx.

Comment: A look into the documentation reveals: **The style sgamevar.sty (but not sgame.sty) is compatible with beamer. Both styles are incompatible with the memoir class and with tablularx.sty and array.sty (and hence any package, like jurabib.sty, that loads
array.sty)**. I understand this that there is incompatibility with `array` and packages based on `array` code. See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sgame/sgame.pdf, on the 1st page, *Introduction* section

Comment: @ChristianHupfer An answer?

Comment: @egreg: I converted my comment to an 'answer' -- Thanks for reminding me of this post

Answer (score 4):

A look into the documentation reveals: The style `sgamevar.sty` (but not `sgame.sty`) is compatible with beamer. Both styles are incompatible with the memoir class and with `tabularx.sty` and `array.sty` (and hence any package, like `jurabib.sty`, that loads `array.sty`).

I understand this that there is incompatibility with array and packages based on array code. See [sgame](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sgame/sgame.pdf), on the 1st page, Introduction section