# Payoff matrix too wide

Tags: matrices

I am trying to do a 3X8 payoff matrix using LaTeX and I have used the following command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{game}{3}{8}[Player~1][Player~2][\(A\)]
      & \(Veto ZXY\) & \(Veto ZXX\) & \(Veto ZZY\)& \(Veto ZZX\)& \(Veto YXY\) & \(Veto YXX\) & \(Veto YZY\)& \(Veto YZX\)\\
\(Veto X\) &\(2,2\) &\(2,2\) &\(2,2\)& \(2,2\) &\(1,3\) &\(1,3\) &\(1,3\)& \(1,3\)\\
\(Veto Y\) &\(1,3\) &\(1,3\) &\(3,1\)& \(3,1\)&\(1,3\) &\(1,3\) &\(3,1\)& \(3,1\)\\
\(Veto Z\) &\(3,1\) &\(2,2\) &\(3,1\)& \(2,2\) &\(3,1\) &\(2,2\) &\(3,1\)& \(2,2\)
\end{game}\hspace*{\fill}
\caption[]{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can imagine, the matrix is too wide and thus I get the following message:

```
Overfull \hbox (121.53635pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 164--171
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the `game`  environment?

Comment: In general, please always post full but minimal examples that illustrate your problem. The example should be such that others can test your code as is without having to add anything to it.

Comment: I am sorry but it is the first time I ask a question

Comment: The game environment is sgame

Comment: Is it necessary to include `Veto` in every cell? If you remove them the matrix renders fine.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `sgame` package doesn't allow setting column width.

You may use an ordinary table, here is an example with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sgame}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]\centering\small
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cl*{8}{Q[m,c,2.6em]}},
            hline{3-Y}={3-Z}{solid}, 
            vline{3-Z}={3-Y}{solid},
            column{1}={rightsep=0pt,leftsep=0pt},
            row{3-Y}={abovesep=2pt,belowsep=0pt},
            row{Z}={abovesep=5pt},
            column{3-Z}={mode=math},
            row{1-2}={mode=text}
            }
        &&\SetCell[c={8}]{m} Player~2\\
        && Veto \(ZXY\) & Veto \(ZXX\) & Veto \(ZZY\)& Veto \(ZZX\)& Veto \(YXY\) & Veto \(YXX\) & Veto \(YZY\)& Veto \(YZX\)\\
        \SetCell[r={3}]{m}\rotatebox{90}{Player~1}&Veto \(X\) &2,2 &2,2 &2,2& 2,2 &1,3 &1,3 &1,3& 1,3\\
        &Veto \(Y\) &1,3 &1,3&3,1& 3,1&1,3 &1,3 &3,1& 3,1\\
        &Veto \(Z\) &3,1 &2,2 &3,1&2,2 &3,1 &2,2 &3,1& 2,2\\
        &&\SetCell[c={8}]{m} A
    \end{tblr}  
    \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are problems with `sgame`, because it's incompatible with the standard `array` package.

You can use the reimplementation I made at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512953/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with a recent LaTeX release
\usepackage{hhline,array,multirow}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\newcommand\doubleactivetilde{~~} % hhline wants ~ to mean 'column with no line'

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_cfr_game_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l_cfr_game_first_seq
\tl_new:N \l_cfr_game_first_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__cfr_game_first:n
 {
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{game}{mmooob}
 {% #1 = number of rows, #2 = number of columns (besides the label column)
  % #3 = left label, #4 = top label, #5 = bottom label
  % #6 = body

  % split the body at \\
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_cfr_game_body_seq { \\ } { #6 }
  % in case there's a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_cfr_game_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_put_right:NV \l_cfr_game_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl }
  %
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_cfr_game_body_seq \l_cfr_game_first_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_cfr_game_first_seq { & } \l_cfr_game_first_tl
  % discard the first (empty) item
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_cfr_game_first_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}r*{#2}{|c}|}
  % top label
  \IfValueT{#4}{\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{} & \multicolumn{#2}{c}{#4} \\}
  % first row
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \seq_map_function:NN \l_cfr_game_first_seq \__cfr_game_first:n \\
  \exp_args:No \hhline{\doubleactivetilde*{#2}{|-}|}
  \IfValueTF{#3}{\multirow{#1}{*}{#3\quad}}{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{}}
  & \seq_use:Nn \l_cfr_game_body_seq
   { \\ \exp_args:No \hhline{\doubleactivetilde*{#2}{|-}|} & } \\
  \exp_args:No \hhline{\doubleactivetilde*{#2}{|-}|}
  \IfValueT{#5}
   {
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule{0pt}{1.25\normalbaselineskip}} &
    \multicolumn{#2}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{#5}} \\
   }
  \end{tabular}
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering

\begin{game}{3}{8}[Player~1][Player~2][Description]
& \splitcell{Veto \\ ZXY}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ ZXX}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ ZZY}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ ZZX}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ YXY}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ YXX}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ YZY}
& \splitcell{Veto \\ YZX}\\
Veto X &2,2 &2,2 &2,2& 2,2 &1,3 &1,3 &1,3& 1,3\\
Veto Y &1,3 &1,3 &3,1& 3,1&1,3 &1,3 &3,1& 3,1\\
Veto Z &3,1 &2,2 &3,1& 2,2 &3,1 &2,2 &3,1& 2,2
\end{game}

\caption{The global caption to the matrix}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{10}{c}}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
    &       & \Block{1-*}{Player 2} \\
    &       & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  \\ 
    &       & ZXY   & ZXX   & ZZY   & ZZX   & YXY   & YXX   & YZY   & YZX   \\
\Block{3-1}<\rotate>{Player 1}
    &Veto X & \Block[hvlines]{3-*}{}
              2,2   & 2,2   & 2,2   & 2,2   & 1,3   & 1,3   & 1,3   & 1,3   \\  
    &Veto Y & 1,3   & 1,3   & 3,1   & 3,1   & 1,3   & 1,3   & 3,1   & 3,1   \\
    &Veto Z & 3,1   & 2,2   & 3,1   & 2,2   & 3,1   & 2,2   & 3,1   & 2,2   \\
    &       &  \Block{1-*}{A} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

As table, similar to @CarLaTeX answer with slightly shorter code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{cells = c,
             hline{4-Y} = {3-Z}{solid}, vline{3-Z} = {4-Y}{solid},
             colsep=4pt,
             row{2}={rowsep=-1pt},
            }
    &       &   \SetCell[c=8]{c} Player 2 
                    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
    &       & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  & Veto  \\ 
    &       & ZXY   & ZXX   & ZZY   & ZZX   & YXY   & YXX   & YZY   & YZX   \\
\SetCell[r=3]{c}    Player 1 
    &Veto X & 2,2   & 2,2   & 2,2   & 2,2   & 1,3   & 1,3   & 1,3   & 1,3   \\  
    &Veto Y & 1,3   & 1,3   & 3,1   & 3,1   & 1,3   & 1,3   & 3,1   & 3,1   \\
    &Veto Z & 3,1   & 2,2   & 3,1   & 2,2   & 3,1   & 2,2   & 3,1   & 2,2   \\
    &       &   \SetCell[c=8]{c}    A
                    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{A caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]