# Reproduce a simple table

Tags: tables

How can I reproduce this table using Latex?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  What difficulties are you encountering?

Comment: You can look at `sgame`, which however has incompatibilities with other important packages. Or you can use the code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512953/4427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a combination of \multicolumn command (to add vertical lines in the table) together with the \cline command (to add horizontal lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Giocatore 2} \\ 
    & &  Sinistra & Centro \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Giocatore 1} & Su & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1, 0} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1, 2} \\ \cline{3-4}
    & Giu &  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 3}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{0, 1}\\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The code produces the following table:

[image]

This Overleaf link is extremely useful when dealing with LaTex table formatting: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses left-alignment for columns 1 and 2 and fixed-width centered alignment for columns 3 and 4. Observe that there's no line break, *by construction*, in the string "Giocatore 1".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\addto\extrasitalian{\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}    % optional, to match font used in OP's screenshot
\usepackage{array}                  % for 'w' column type
\usepackage[labelfont=sc]{caption}  % small caps
\usepackage{multirow}               % for '\multirow' macro

\counterwithin{figure}{section}     % just for this example
%% Two handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}  
\newcommand\mr[2][2]{\multirow{#1}{*}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\stepcounter{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}  % default is '1'
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l | w{c}{2cm} | w{c}{2cm} | }
                 & \mc{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Giocatore 2} \\
                 & \mc{} & \mc{Sinistra} & \mc{Destra} \\ \cline{3-4}
\mr{Giocatore 1} & Su    & 1, 0          & 1, 2        \\ \cline{3-4}
                 & Giù   & 0, 3          & 0, 1        \\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{} % generate caption with just a number, no text
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}
                         &     & \Block{1-2}{Giocatore 2} \\
                         &     & Sinistra & Destra \\
\Block{2-1}{Giocatore 1} & Su  & \Block[hvlines]{2-2}{}
                                 $1,0$    & $1,2$ \\
                         & Giù & $0,3$    & $0,1$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]